# counting lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ for a finite field $k$

Tags: finite-fields, projective-space

For an assignment I have to count the number of lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ (for a finite field $k$, so for example $F_q$) using the following definition:

Let $k$ be a field and $n>0$. A line in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ is a set of the form
$\{{[x_0 : x_1 : . . . : x_n] ∈ \mathbb{P}_k^n | (x_0, x_1, . . . , x_n) ∈ V − {0}}\}$
where $V$ is a plane (i.e. a 2-dimensional linear subspace) in $k^{n+1} = A_k^{n+1}$.

As far as I understand projective space, lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ correspond to points in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n-1}$. Because lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$ correspond to planes in $A_k^{n+1}$, which are lines in $A_k^{n}$, which correspond to points in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n-1}$. 
 Can I instead of counting lines in $\mathbb{P}_k^n$  just count points in $\mathbb{P}_k^{n+1}$?

Comment: Wouldn't it be that a point in $\mathbb P^n$ is a line in $\mathbb P^{n+1}$

Comment: You are right, I changed it now

Comment: No, a plane in $A^{n+1}$ is not the same as a line in $A^n$.

Comment: yes, I can see that there is a flaw. Any ideas on how to count those lines?